# combine two rows in R merging data and remove duplicates

Tags: r, database, csv, data-cleaning

I'm working on cleaning a database with emails and their respective information. Some emails appear more than one time but the information from one row to an other is complementary. So i want to combine the rows using email as the key. and remove the emails in the case the information is just duplicated.

My database is a csv file and using read.csv to convert it to a data frame.

**Input**

```
  EMAIL     Country     Gender        Language
1 y@y.com   US                           S
2 z@z.com   AR           female          S
3 z@z.com                female          
4 s@f.com   US           female          E
4 s@f.com   US           female          E
5 y@y.com   US           male
```

**Output**

```
  EMAIL     Country     Gender        Language
1 y@y.com   US           male            S
2 z@z.com   AR           female          S
3 s@f.com   US           female          E
```

Answer (score 4):

We can also use `aggregate` for a base R option:

```
df_out <- aggregate(x=df, by=list(df$EMAIL), function(x) { max(x, na.rm=TRUE) })
df_out[order(df_out$EMAIL), -1]

    EMAIL Country Gender Language
1 s@f.com      US female        E
2 y@y.com      US   male        S
3 z@z.com      AR female        S
```

The basic idea here is that we arbitrarily take the max value of each column, for each email key, while ignoring `NA` values.  This would appear to work for your data set.

**Data:**

```
df <- data.frame(EMAIL=c('y@y.com', 'z@z.com', 'z@z.com', 's@f.com', 's@f.com', 'y@y.com'),
                 Country=c('US', 'AR', NA, 'US', 'US', 'US'),
                 Gender=c(NA, 'female', 'female', 'female', 'female', 'male'),
                 Language=c('S', 'S', NA, 'E', 'E', NA), stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
```

### Demo

Comment: This fails when a field is all NA for an email key.

Answer (score 2):

We can use `dplyr`.  After grouping by 'EMAIL', get the `unique` elements of each of the column which are not a blank using `summarise_all`

```
library(dplyr)
df %>%
   group_by(EMAIL) %>%
   summarise_all(funs(unique(.[.!='']))) 
# A tibble: 3 x 4
# Groups: EMAIL [3]
#  EMAIL   Country Gender Language
#  <chr>   <chr>   <chr>  <chr>   
#1 y@y.com US      male   S       
#2 z@z.com AR      female S       
#3 s@f.com US      female E
```

#### data

```
df <- structure(list(EMAIL = c("y@y.com", "z@z.com", "z@z.com", "s@f.com", 
"s@f.com", "y@y.com"), Country = c("US", "AR", "", "US", "US", 
"US"), Gender = c("", "female", "female", "female", "female", 
"male"), Language = c("S", "S", "", "E", "E", "")), .Names = c("EMAIL", 
 "Country", "Gender", "Language"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c("1", 
"2", "3", "4", "5", "6"))
```